# Decompositions of Euclidean spaces by nontrivial continua

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, partitions

First, a brief introduction of the context. A *usc* decomposition of a metric space $X$ is a collection $G$ of compact sets which vary semicontinuously. I will be interested in *cellular* decompositions of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (that is, the elements of $G$ are decreasing intersections of closed balls).

In 1967, [Jones proved](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-74/issue-1/The-impossibility-of-filling-En-with-arcs/bams/1183529403.full) that it is not possible to fill $\mathbb{R}^n$ with disjoint arcs. This came after [Roberts had proven](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-2/issue-1/Collections-filling-a-plane/10.1215/S0012-7094-36-00202-8.short) that the plane can be decomposed by cellular sets none of which is a point (or equivalently, there is a lower bound on the diameter of the sets).

After some time searching the web, etc, I've found out that there has been a lot of progress towards the understanding of cellular decompositions of manifolds (see [Daverman's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=qyPRlNDbVksC&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=daverman+decompositions+of+manifolds&source=bl&ots=QfiROu4AP4&sig=ptShJY6SgSrpozg9I2pn7QbSD10&hl=es&ei=sKW9TIDfLJSI4gaD3unQAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result#v=onepage&q&f=false)) but some kind of questions have been somewhat not treated.

Is there some progress towards the understanding of cellular decompositions of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with all of the elements of diameter bounded from below? In particular, I am interested in the following questions:

Q1) What is the possible topology of the sets constituting such a decomposition? Mainly, which kind of possible topologies are compatible, etc.

In general (at least in dimension 2) such a decomposition is equivalent to the existence of a surjective continuous map $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the preimage of every point is an element of $G$ (in particular, compact connected and cellular).

> So, assuming $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to  \mathbb{R}^n$ is a surjective
> continuous map such that the preimage of each point is cellular and of
> diameter bigger than $0$

Q2) What kind of preimages may arcs have under $f$? Or disks? What is the topology of this sets?

And the question I am most interested in is:

Q3) Consider an open set $U\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(U)$ is open: Does it hold that $U$ contains a fiber of $f$ (that is, a set of the form $f^{-1}(x)$)?

Answers in dimension $2$ are already very interesting to me. Other related references will be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting that space cannot be filled with arcs, because it can be filled with disjoint loops (or "hoops"): http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/forum/hoops_links/khoops.html .

Comment: Thanks! However, I am mostly interested in decompositions in sets which are *cellular*, this imposes more restrictions. 